# find closed contour for sample image using opencv

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, contour

I am having problem in finding closed contour box for my image:

[image: Input Image]

My problem is I have to create rectangle around brown box so as to perform operation only on box. (here, the box is just an example. It can be of different color with different background).

I am currently using `Canny` for edge detection and `cv2.findContour` for contour box detection, although it's pretty close for height but for width contours from background creating mess and adding into the width as can be seen below:

[image: Target Image]

Below is the code I wrote for this:

```
            import cv2
            import imutils

            img = cv2.imread(img)
            image = imutils.resize(img, width=600)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 15, 200,True)
            edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=2)
            edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=2)
            
            edged = 255-edged
            cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
            
            for c in cnts:
                # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
                if cv2.contourArea(c) < 300:
                    continue
                orig = image.copy()
                
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                cv2.rectangle(orig,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
                cv2.drawContours(orig, c, -1, (255, 255, 0), 3)
                
                # show the output image
                cv2.imshow("Image", orig)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is there any other approach I can follow which is easy like above or modify some part to achieve my task to create rectangle around box?

Comment: Its very hard to write a code that addresses all the situations to find box in the image. You need machine learning and neural nets for that. If you want simple OpenCV code for your task, you need to make sure your input image conditions are ideal for it to work.

Comment: ya i was also thinking about that , Also for this use case thinking of about blank background will help , Is there any method in opencv by which I can extract contours with shape like rectangles only.., or some ways in which i can separate foreground with background ? I was also thinking of some ways to only extract lines with horizontal and vertical values with (+/- 10 degree relaxation), but didn't got any methods by searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use simple OpenCV functions to detect the box, you'll have to make sure the input image conditions are ideal. Like distinct background color from box etc.

First convert the image to HSV color space and segment out the box. Use the following trackbar code to figure out the proper values -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('img')


cv2.createTrackbar('lH','img',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hH','img',255,255,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lS','img',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hS','img',255,255,nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar('lV','img',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('hV','img',255,255,nothing)



while(True):

    ret,frame = cap.read()

    l_H = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lH', 'img')
    h_H = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hH', 'img')
    l_S = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lS', 'img')
    h_S = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hS', 'img')
    l_V = cv2.getTrackbarPos('lV', 'img')
    h_V = cv2.getTrackbarPos('hV', 'img')

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_hsv = np.array([l_H, l_S, l_V])
    higher_hsv = np.array([h_H, h_S, h_V])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, higher_hsv)

    frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('image', mask)
    if(cv2.waitKey(10)==27):break
```

Perform morphological operations if needed. If your background is distinct, simply finding contours and bounding box will get you the box.

If not, you can find the horizontal and vertical lines as shown in this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html).

To find polygons in an image, [check this.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/)

You can use a proper combination of these to find your box.